# How to early-fetch without waiting for all childrens to be mounted?

Tags: reactjs, performance

I have the following React component structure:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C/>
  </B>
</A>
```

I fetch data in component `A`. Currently, I put the fetch logic in `componentDidMount`. But based on 
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v15.0.1/docs/docs/ref-03-component-specs.md#mounting-componentdidmount:

> The componentDidMount() method of child components is invoked before that of parent components.

So, the fetching only happens after `A`, `B`, and `C` are mounted & rendered

Since in our case, `A` has deeply nested components, the fetching needs to wait all those components rendered and mounted.

Is there a way to do fetch earlier?

Comment: Not tested : What if you use `componentWillMount` on A ?

Comment: Because it's going to be deprecated in React 17. And I think `componentWillMount` is designed not for this kind of task

Comment: Second solution : With a state on A and a simple if. `if (this.state.isLoading === false) {<B><C /></B>}`. I used this (bad) solution. <A> will automatically rerender on `isLoading` state update

Comment: @JulienBourdic Interesting work around, will try

Comment: are you looking for a solution like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ekn2k8 ?

Comment: Thx @JulienBourdic, we managed to make it up to 2 second faster!

Comment: Also thx for the code snippet @Jayavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to improve the performance, up to 2 second faster by following @Julien Bourdic and @Jayavel recommendation in the comment section above:

```
      state = {
        isReady: false
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        fetch();
        this.setState({ isReady: true });
      }

      render() {
        return this.state.isReady ? <Wrapped {...this.props} /> : null;
      }
```

Basically we render `null` when fetching is not finished. This way, component `B` and `C` won't be mounted & rendered, allowing `A`'s `componentDidMount` (and `fetch`) to start earlier.

Answer (score 1):

> The componentDidMount() method of child components is invoked before that of parent components.

While you're doing something asynchronous, show a loading spinner or something until all the info is fetched like below:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState(() => {
          return { data , isLoading: false};
        })
      );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading ...</p>; // initially isLoading is true, it renders a loading after fetch components will render
    }
    return (
      <div>
      <ul>
        {this.state.data.map(data => {
          return <li key={data.username}>{data.username} </li>
        })}
      </ul>
        <Hello name={this.state.name}>
          <p>
            Start editing to see some magic happen :)
          </p>
        </Hello>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ekn2k8)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using React's lifecycle methods, a good option would be to not render the children of this component until componentDidMount is called and your data fetch is out. You could use `setState` to manage this.

Alternatively you could look into making data fetches outside of the React lifecycle. This can be a good option depending on what kind of state management solution you use and the general architecture of your app.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not recommended? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor => "Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in the constructor. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead."

Comment: It isn't but you are explicitly looking to avoid the recommended way, so there's not going to be a great solution. As an alternative, you can make fetches completely outside of the React lifecycle - though that depends a lot on how your app is structured.